# Cloudfoundry integration on-premises application

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am currently making my thesis about the integration of PAAS platforms with on-premises application. Google app engine has his Secure Data Connector and Windows has Service Bus Relay.

Now I am looking for the same middleware in Cloud Foundry. Does anyone know if Cloud Foundry has some sort of middleware to communicate with on-premises applications?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something that gives a secure connection from CF back to the corporate datacenter to access resources there?

You may have a database behind a firewall - how can a CF app access that? well it can't.

I would also recommend you to follow up conversations in here:

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev